# Bash script: Matching extended glob pattern to a string array

Tags: bash, extglob

Hello Amazing People,

I have been trying to achieve a goal of matching an extended glob pattern to a string array (file paths) and getting the list of file which matches to the pattern. Below is the code which works for one ext glob pattern but not for the other similar ext glob pattern.

This is the pattern which doesn't work.
`pattern="**cars-+(!(bad-cats|dogs))/src/bin/out/**"`

Here is the shell code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Enable extended globbing
shopt -s extglob


# pattern="**cars-!(bad-cats)/src/bin/out/**" # this extended glob pattern works 
pattern="**cars-+(!(bad-cats|dogs))/src/bin/out/**" # this extended glob pattern doesn't work and also goes in a very long loop cos of cars-ok-kk/src/main/out/start.txt

files="cars-white-pens/src/bin/out/file.txt,cars-ok-kk/src/main/out/start.txt,cars-grey-dogs/src/bin/out/bottle.txt,cars-bad-cats/src/bin/out/computer.txt,cars-whales/src/bin/mouse.txt,cars-dogs/src/bin/out/mouse.txt"
IFS=',' read -r -a files_array <<< "$files"

matching_files=""

for file in "${files_array[@]}"; do
  if [[ $file == $pattern ]]; then
    if [ -z "$matching_files" ]; then
      matching_files="$file"
    else
      matching_files="$matching_files,$file"
    fi
  fi
done

echo "Match: $matching_files"
```

PS: We can change the ext glob pattern too if needed for the code to work but I want the pattern to be ext glob pattern only with support of exclusion of one or more directories as shown in the pattern.

Thanks in advance.

The commented ext glob pattern `pattern="**cars-!(bad-cats)/src/bin/**"` works fine with the shell script but the other one doesn't.

When I run it, it takes some time (not sure why) and then prints below:

`Match: cars-white-pens/src/bin/out/file.txt,cars-grey-dogs/src/bin/out/bottle.txt,cars-bad-cats/src/bin/out/computer.txt,cars-dogs/src/bin/out/mouse.txt`

It removed `src/main/out` and `src/bin/mouse.txt` but failed to remove `cars-bad-cats` and `cars-dogs` file strings.

I expect output as `Match: cars-white-pens/src/bin/out/file.txt,cars-grey-dogs/src/bin/out/bottle.txt` since `src/main/out` and `src/bin/mouse.txt` doesn't match and `cars-bad-cats` and `cars-dogs` is excluded.

Comment: Does the glob pattern work as expected when matching filenames in a directory?

Comment: Something odd happens with the `+(!(x|y))` pattern but you might be able to make that work as you want to by using `@` instead of `+`.

Furthermore you can simplify it to just `!(x|y)`.

Comment: @Barmar the glob pattern works as expected when matching filenames. See here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2A%2Acars-%2B%28%21%28bad-cats%7Cdogs%29%29%2Fsrc%2Fbin%2Fout%2F%2A%2A&matches=false&tests=cars-white-pens%2Fsrc%2Fbin%2Fout%2Ffile.txt&tests=cars-ok-kk%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fout%2Fstart.txt&tests=cars-grey-dogs%2Fsrc%2Fbin%2Fout%2Fbottle.txt&tests=cars-bad-cats%2Fsrc%2Fbin%2Fout%2Fcomputer.txt&tests=cars-whales%2Fsrc%2Fbin%2Fmouse.txt&tests=cars-dogs%2Fsrc%2Fbin%2Fout%2Fmouse.txt

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but a workaround:

```
case $file in
*cars-bad-cats/* | *cars-dogs/* ) ;;
*cars-*/src/bin/out/* )
    matching_files=${matching_files:+$matching_files,}$file
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

`+(!(bad-cats|dogs))` matches `bad-cats` because it can (for instance) match it as strings `bad` followed by `-cats`, neither of which matches `bad-cats` or `dogs` (so the `!(dogs|bad-cats)` pattern matches both of them). Similarly, `dogs` can be matched as strings `do` followed by `gs`.

To fix the code change the `pattern` assignment to:

```
pattern='*cars-!(dogs|bad-cats)/src/bin/out/*'
```

- The pattern `!(bad-cats|dogs)` does not match either`bad-cats` or `dogs` because it doesn't allow them to be broken into parts that can be matched separately.
- Removing the `+(` and corresponding `)` in the pattern also massively speeds up the matching because it eliminates huge amounts of pointless backtracking.
- I replaced each of two occurrences of `**` in the original pattern with `*` because the second `*` is redundant, and might make pattern matching slower.  (`**` is only special when doing [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) and the `globstar` shell option is enabled (see the [globstar](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#globstar_.28since_bash_4.0-alpha.29) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)).)